# ie parallax scrolling flickering/jumping with fixed background images

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer, parallax

First of all, sorry for my english.
I am creating a parallax website with Skrollr plugin. I am using a img with position fixed, with the css3 transform:translate I move the img. its work great in almost all the browsers in mac and pc apart from ie9/10. In IE, when i scroll, the image is jumping/flickering/lagging. when i remove the fixed from the position css and change it to absolute, its move clearly and smoothly, but i most use fixed elements.

```
<div class="full-bg"data-784="transform: translateY(-1118px);"   data-2223="transform: translateY( -1718px) "><img src="images/hp/visitor-center.jpg"  /></div>

#visitor-center{
width: 100%;
height: 877px;
float: right;
overflow: hidden;

position: relative;
top:0px;
background-size: 100%;
}
#visitor-center .full-bg{
width: 100%;
position: fixed;
z-index: -1;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-ms-transform:translate(0px,100px); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform:translate(0px,100px); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
transform:translate(0px,100px); /* Standard syntax */

}
#visitor-center .full-bg img{
width: 100%;
}
```

here an example i found that use fixed background. in other browser apart from ie its work great. but ie screw everything.
any suggestions what can i do?

Comment: Welcome to being a designer, this is one of the continual hurdles that you will face. 2 choices, and the answer to both is the question, *do I care about IE?*. 1) IE specific code, or 2) See answer to question.

Comment: haha Its not the first time of course. but until now i always found solutions to the latest ie. I will be happy to find first of all the reason for this and maybe a good solution. I know its happen beacuse of the position fixed, but why?